# PHP set variable from array

Tags: php, variables, zen-cart

I am trying to set a variable `$za_play` to the `clip_filename` of the product from this script. I'm confused by the array to get multiple clips, I only have 1 clip per product. How can I set `$za_play` to the clips filename?

```
<?php
/**
 * iterates thru media collections/clips
 *
 * @package productTypes
 * @copyright Copyright 2003-2009 Zen Cart Development Team
 * @license http://www.zen-cart.com/license/2_0.txt GNU Public License V2.0
 * @version $Id: media_manager.php 11825 2009-01-15 09:46:19Z drbyte $
 */
if (!defined('IS_ADMIN_FLAG')) {
  die('Illegal Access');
}

/**
 * get list of media collections assigned to specified product
 */
$zv_collection_query = "select media_id, product_id from " . TABLE_MEDIA_TO_PRODUCTS . "
                        where product_id = '" . (int)$_GET['products_id'] . "'";
$zq_collections = $db->Execute($zv_collection_query);
$zv_product_has_media = false;
**$za_play = 'HELLO';**
/**
 * loop thru collections to identify actual media clips
 */
if ($zq_collections->RecordCount() > 0) {
  $zv_product_has_media = true;
  while (!$zq_collections->EOF) {
    /**
     * get names of assigned media collections
     */
    $zf_media_manager_query = "select media_id, media_name from " . TABLE_MEDIA_MANAGER . "
                               where media_id = '" . (int)$zq_collections->fields['media_id'] . "'";
    $zq_media_manager = $db->Execute($zf_media_manager_query);
    if ($zq_media_manager->RecordCount() < 1) {
      $zv_product_has_media = false;
    } else {
      /**
       * build array of [collection_id][text] = collection-name
       */
      $za_media_manager[$zq_media_manager->fields['media_id']] = array('text' => $zq_media_manager->fields['media_name']);
      /**
       * get list of media clips associated with the current media collection, sorted by filename (to allow display sort order to be controlled by filename)
       */
      $zv_clips_query = "select media_id, clip_id, clip_filename, clip_type from " . TABLE_MEDIA_CLIPS . "
                         where media_id = '" . (int)$zq_media_manager->fields['media_id'] . "' order by clip_filename";
      $zq_clips = $db->Execute($zv_clips_query);
      if ($zq_clips->RecordCount() < 1) {
        $zv_product_has_media = false;
      } else {
        while (!$zq_clips->EOF) {
          /**
           * get list of media types and filenames associated with the current media
           * @TODO - run this as separate static array, since only needs to run once, not repeatedly in a loop
           */
          $zf_clip_type_query = "select type_ext, type_name from " . TABLE_MEDIA_TYPES . "
                                 where type_id = '" . (int)$zq_clips->fields['clip_type'] . "'";

          $zq_clip_type = $db->Execute($zf_clip_type_query);

          $za_media_manager[$zq_media_manager->fields['media_id']]['clips'][$zq_clips->fields['clip_id']] =
                array('clip_filename' => $zq_clips->fields['clip_filename'],
                      'clip_type' => $zq_clip_type->fields['type_name']);
          $zq_clips->MoveNext();

        }
      }
    }
    $zq_collections->MoveNext();
  }
}
$zv_product_has_media = (sizeof($za_media_manager)) > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

**$za_play = $zq_clips->fields['clip_filename'];**
```

Comment: If the queries aren't returning multiple things, why are you using `while` loops to process the results?

Comment: I don't know how to change it to return a single result. Is it still possible to grab the first clip_filename result into $za_play without removing the while loop?

Comment: Just remove the `while` loops. If the queries only return 1 row, then the loop only executes once -- when it tries again `EOF` will be true.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but no luck. I am a very noobie to coding. Can you show me what to take out?

Answer (score 0):

This just sets `$za_play` and `$zv_product_has_media`, it doesn't bother creating all the other arrays that your original code creates.

```
$zv_collection_query = "select media_id, product_id from " . TABLE_MEDIA_TO_PRODUCTS . "
                        where product_id = '" . (int)$_GET['products_id'] . "'";
$zq_collections = $db->Execute($zv_collection_query);
$zv_product_has_media = false;
$za_play = 'HELLO';
/**
 * loop thru collections to identify actual media clips
 */
if ($zq_collections->RecordCount() > 0) {
    $zv_product_has_media = true;
    /**
     * get names of assigned media collections
     */
    $zf_media_manager_query = "select media_id, media_name from " . TABLE_MEDIA_MANAGER . "
                               where media_id = '" . (int)$zq_collections->fields['media_id'] . "'";
    $zq_media_manager = $db->Execute($zf_media_manager_query);
    if ($zq_media_manager->RecordCount() < 1) {
        $zv_product_has_media = false;
    } else {
        $zv_clips_query = "select media_id, clip_id, clip_filename, clip_type from " . TABLE_MEDIA_CLIPS . "
                         where media_id = '" . (int)$zq_media_manager->fields['media_id'] . "' order by clip_filename";
        $zq_clips = $db->Execute($zv_clips_query);
        if ($zq_clips->RecordCount() < 1) {
            $zv_product_has_media = false;
        } else {
            $za_play = $zq_clips->fields['clip_filename'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much. But when I call $za_play from a different script it still returns as HELLO?

Comment: Is this code in a function? If so, you need to return the value from the function, or declare `global $za_play`.

Comment: What is the value of `$zv_product_has_media`? Maybe one of the queries isn't finding anything.

Comment: $za_product_has_media is True

Comment: Then I don't see how it could be failing to set `$za_play`. Look at all the `if` statements -- they set it to `false` if you don't get to the line that assigns `za_play` at the bottom.

Comment: Can I remove all the if statements?

Comment: You could, if you don't mind that there's no checking for a failed query. I don't think it matters.